# Strip Markdown text from files

Tags: regex, markdown

I'm using leanpub.com and imported my blog, but accidentally left it to import images.  I don't want that so now I want to strip the images from about 2,000 individual markup files.  If you're familiar with markdown you'll know an image is designated like such

```
![optional alt text](url/link "optional title")
```

**update**: upon further inspection a few images are also links so they are contained like this:

```
[![alt text](image link "title text")](url image links to)
```

**sample text**:

```
[![Hollywood: An Empire of Their Own (A&E DVD Archives)](images/51EEVBAA32L._SL160_.jpg)Hollywood: An Empire of Their Own (A&E DVD Archives)](http://www.amazon.com/Hollywood-Empire-Their-Own-Archives/dp/B0009HMTEO?SubscriptionId=08NDXT4K5C4JPKBB4702&tag=amz&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B0009HMTEO)This 
"lucid, inviting work of social history" (The New York Times) highlights the 
bold and enduring vision of the Jewish immigrants who founded Hollywood and reinvented American culture.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just strip out everything between the tokens `![` and `)`. Note that the optional trailing space is important, since links can be surrounded by other text.

```
sed --in-place='.bak' 's/!\[.*)[[:space:]]\?//' [file ...]
```

Comment: I just added an update, in case of an image that is contained within a link.  Would this still work?  I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I think you mean [.*]   Not [.*)

Comment: This also doesn't work for nested brackets ( a link that contains a set of brackets for example)